# How to get a connection object in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2, database

I am trying to get a connection object in my magento2 controller. Tried all google but still not able to get it working... any help?

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace Silver\Customize\Controller\Index;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\ConnectionFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $pageFactory;
    protected $resource;
    protected $connectionFactory = null;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory, ConnectionFactory $connectionFactory)
    {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->connectionFactory = $connectionFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);

    }

    public function execute()
    {        
        // var_dump(__METHOD__);
        $page_object = $this->pageFactory->create();
        return $page_object;
    } 
}
?>
```

And here is the error which I am getting:

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 3 passed to Silver\Customize\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\ConnectionFactory, none given, called in C:\wamp\www\magento\var\generation\Silver\Customize\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\Silver\Customize\Controller\Index\Index.php on line 14
```

---

This is my code: fails here itself

```
    <?php
namespace Silver\Customize\Controller\Index;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{
    protected $pageFactory;
    protected $connection;
    protected $resource;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory, ResourceConnection  $resource ) 
    {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        return parent::__construct($context);

    }

    public function execute()
    {        
        // var_dump(__METHOD__);
        $page_object = $this->pageFactory->create();

        //$coreResource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); // This does not work... let me show
        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection(ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);


        return $page_object;
    } 


}

?>
```

And this is the error:

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 3 passed to Silver\Customize\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection, none given, called in C:\wamp\www\magento\var\generation\Silver\Customize\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\Silver\Customize\Controller\Index\Index.php on line 17
```

Comment: What do you mean by Connection object?

Comment: Why have you posted this question as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 10):

the connection resource is

```
  protected  _resource;
  public function __construct(Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource)
  {
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    parent::__construct($context);

  }
```

inject .
for getting :

```
$connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
```

get table :

```
$tblSalesOrder = $connection->getTableName('sales_order');
```

select rows :

```
$result1 = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT quote_id FROM `'.$tblSalesOrder.'` WHERE entity_id='.$orderId);
```

the source of complete course from [here](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-programming-get-default-core-write-and-read-resource-row-direct-sql)

Comment: This is my code:

Comment: no try to use the class ResourceConnection directly and not the ConnectionFactory

Comment: Is use connectionFactory required?